# Rule with using listView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any important rule to use items into `listview` or using `listview` into a column or `listview` beside a `gridview`?

I got many errors in this area for scrollable items.

Comment: Add code for better understanding

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

1- if you are using listview inside a column , you should add the parameter **shrinkwrap : ture** in the listview.

2- if you are using nested listviews , you should add the parameter **physics: ClampingScrollPhysics()** in the inner listviews in addition to the **shrinkwrap parameter = true** NO.1

code sample : 
1-

```
Column(
  children:<Widget>[
      ListView(
         shrinkWrap:true 
        children:<Widget>[
        //your code
       ]
     )
     ]
);
```

2-

```
ListView(
       children:<Widget>[
     ListView(
       physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap :true,
     children: <Widget>[]
       )
      ]
  )
```

I hope that could help